# Including JS files compiled using Figwheel to Uberjar built

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, uberjar, figwheel

Here is Figwheel config, `app.cljs.edn`

```clj
^{:watch-dirs ["src/cljs" "src/cljc"]}
{:modules
 {:aff {:entries #{asaas.aff.aff}
        :output-to "target/public/js/aff.js"}
  :loc {:entries #{asaas.aff.loc}
        :output-to "target/public/js/loc.js"}  
  :user {:entries #{asaas.user.user}
         :output-to "target/public/js/user.js"}
  :auth {:entries #{asaas.auth.auth}
         :output-to "target/public/js/auth.js"}}
 :output-dir "target/public/js/app"
 :asset-path "/js/app",
 }
```

The problem is, it just works in `dev`. How should I go about including compiled JS files in my `.jar`, created by `uberjar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified `app.cljs.edn` to,

```clj
^{:watch-dirs ["src/cljs" "src/cljc"]}
{:modules
 {:aff {:entries #{asaas.aff.aff}}
  :loc {:entries #{asaas.aff.loc}}
  :user {:entries #{asaas.user.user}}
  :auth {:entries #{asaas.auth.auth}}}

 :output-dir "resources/public/js/app"
 :asset-path "/js/app"}
```

Now it's getting packaged.

**Note:** Omission of `:output-to` is not the key; changing `target/` to `resources/` did the trick. And please, advise me on the best practices. Thanks.

Comment: From the documentation on :output-to on https://figwheel.org/docs/compile_config.html, it states that the output dir should be merged with files from resources to keep them separate from version control. Given examples like https://kozieiev.com/blog/packaging-clojure-into-jar-uberjar-with-tools-build/, I suspect the issue is the resources directory needs to be copied into target, then figwheel compilation can merge on top of that in target, and then bundling of the target directory into an uberjar.